# Add a column in Microsoft Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm playing around with Azure ML Studio. Now I would like to add a new column in my dataset to calculate and in a further step to cluster my data. What's the best way to do it? I tried to add a column with sql (alter table) but it didn't work.

btw. the "add columns" function only adds columns from another dataset...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Apply SQL Transformation" module should be able to do it. For example, I have a dataset with an *age* column and here's the SQL to create another column called *double_age*:

```
select age, age * 2 as double_age from t1;
```

Which produces a dataset with just the *age* and *double_age* columns:

[image]